# How is it that I can circumvent "cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time" with semantically equivalent code?

Tags: rust

I have the following for a merge sort problem with huge files:

```
struct MergeIterator<'a, T> where T: Copy {
    one: &'a mut dyn Iterator<Item=T>,
    two: &'a mut dyn Iterator<Item=T>,
    a: Option<T>,
    b: Option<T>
}

impl<'m, T> MergeIterator<'m, T> where T: Copy {
    pub fn new(i1: &'m mut dyn Iterator<Item=T>, 
               i2: &'m mut dyn Iterator<Item=T>) -> MergeIterator<'m, T> {
        let mut m = MergeIterator {one:i1, two:i2, a: None, b: None};
        m.a = m.one.next();
        m.b = m.two.next();
        m
    }
}
```

This seems to make rustc happy. However, I started with this (imho) less clumsy body of the `new()` function:

```
MergeIterator {one:i1, two:i2, a: i1.next(), b: i2.next()}
```

and got harsh feedback from the compiler saying

```
cannot borrow `*i1` as mutable more than once at a time
```

and likewise for i2.

I'd like to understand where the semantic difference is between initializing the data elements through the m.one reference vs the i1 argument? Why must I write clumsy  imperative code here to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably be clearer if you write it in lines so that the sequence of operations is visible:

```rust
MergeIterator {
    one: i1,
    two: i2,
    a: i1.next(),
    b: i2.next(),
}
```

You're giving `i1` to the new struct, you don't have it anymore to call `next`.

The solution is to change the order of operations to call `next` first before giving away the mutable reference:

```rust
MergeIterator {
    a: i1.next(),
    b: i2.next(),
    one: i1,
    two: i2,
}
```

To make it clearer, you must understand that `i1.next()` borrows i1 only for the time of the function call while `i1` gives away the mutable reference. Reversing the order isn't equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. I wasn't aware of the point that the order of naming the fields in a constructor was significant. I've always seen it as kind of an atomic all-or-nothing thing.  It would be nice if the compiler would take the burden to figure the correct order out for himself, if there is one.

Comment: @Ingo In this case, it's simple, but in general, reordering could change the meaning of the code because function calls could be reordered and change the sequence of side-effects (e.g. here `i1.next()` is a side effect on `i1`, and the `one:` _could_ be `one: something_that_calls_next(i1)` which would have a side effect on `i1` as well as moving it), and so instead the compiler _never_ does that.

Comment: @KevinReid I understand. The compiler could only do this if there was referential integrity which is impossible to achieve in the presence of mutations.